# Get with Basic Auth Ruby doesn't work

Tags: ruby, authentication, get

I need to make a GET request in a public api. I know the login and password data are correct but the api returns authentication error. By postman the request is made successfully. The problem is in the same ruby code.

code:

```
    nfe_key = '41170608187168000160550010000001561000000053'
    params = {'grupo' => 'edoc','cnpj' => '08187168000160', 'ChaveNota' => nfe_key, 'Url' => '1'} 

    url = URI.parse('https://managersaashom.tecnospeed.com.br:7071/ManagerAPIWeb/nfe/imprime')

    get = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
    get.basic_auth 'admin', '123mudar'
    get.set_form_data(params)

    request = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    request.read_timeout = 500 #seconds
    request.use_ssl = true
    request.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    response = request.start {|http| http.request(get) }

    puts response.body
```

I make a request on a POST route in the same way and it WORKS. I do not understand why with GET does not work.

With post method works:

```
    params = {'grupo' => 'edoc','cnpj' => '08187168000160', 'arquivo' => 'formato=XML
    ' + xml} 
    url = URI.parse('https://managersaashom.tecnospeed.com.br:7071/ManagerAPIWeb/nfe/envia')

    post = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
    post.basic_auth 'admin', '123mudar'
    post.set_form_data(params)

    request = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    request.read_timeout = 500 #seconds
    request.use_ssl = true
    request.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    response = request.start {|http| http.request(post) }

    puts response.body
```

In postman:

url :  https://managersaashom.tecnospeed.com.br:7071/ManagerAPIWeb/nfe/imprime?grupo=edoc&cnpj=08187168000160&ChaveNota=41170608187168000160550010000001561000000053&Url=1

method: post
basic auth:
 username admin 
 password 123mudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case, you can't pass form data to GET method.Look at example bellow, I wrote a piece of code based on examples given in the Net::HTTP docs and tested it on my local - it works. Here's what I have:

```
nfe_key = '41170608187168000160550010000001561000000053'
params = {'grupo' => 'edoc','cnpj' => '08187168000160', 'ChaveNota' => nfe_key, 'Url' => '1'}

uri = URI.parse('https://managersaashom.tecnospeed.com.br:7071/ManagerAPIWeb/nfe/imprime')


# Add params to URI
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( params )

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https',
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth 'admin', '123mudar'

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

  puts response
  puts response.body
 end
```